# Auto reloading of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which appears after clicking on button. It loads from store procedure and receives 10-15 records/5mins on average so user must click Search button again and again to load new records on screen but customer demands that once gridview appears on screen on first click then it should load new records automatically without clicking button. Any thing to do for it ?

.aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSmsComplaints" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" BorderColor="#333333"  Width="550px" OnRowDataBound="GridViewSmsComplaints_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging" >
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" /> 
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recieving Date" DataField="RecievingDate" />  
      <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ToMobileNo" DataField="ToMobileNo" />  --%>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FromMobileNo" DataField="FromMobileNo" /> 
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Message" DataField="Message" >   
         <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsComplaint">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint"  runat="server" />
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.cs code:

```
protected void btnSearchByDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
      DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
      DataTable dt = ManageRecievedMessage.GetSmsComplaintsByDate(fromDate, toDate);
      //GridViewSmsComplaints.Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:keep-all;word-wrap:normal");

      if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
         GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
         GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;
         //gridViewComplaintsBySubject.Visible = false;
      }
      else
      {
         dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
         GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
         GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
         int totalcolums = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = totalcolums;
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data Found for this date combination";
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;
         //gridViewComplaintsBySubject.Visible = false;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      // Handle Exception
   }
}
```

Comment: This is very broad.  But the general term you're looking for is "AJAX".  You might also look into something like SignalR for pushing data from the server to the browser.

Comment: I agree with David, you are looking for a push architecture and not a pull architecture. If you are using ASP.NET, then SignalR http://signalr.net/ is the way to go. It is not hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to call your grid binding function in to caching callback.You can control your call back by your need.

define callback in top of the page like vaiable decalartion

```
  private static CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove = null;
```

add that method in your page

```
 private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
    {
        OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null,
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
     }
```

add call function and call your grid binding function into callback.

```
public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
    {
        // do stuff here if it matches our taskname, like WebRequest
        // re-add our task so it recurs

        //DoCallyourFunction();

        AddTask(k, Convert.ToInt32(v));

    }
```

Call `AddTask("DoStuff", 300);` on page load .

After doing all stuffs your method is now call every 5 minute 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The GridView is a control used to display "static" data. As far as I know there's no automatic mechanism that allows you to update periodically the content of the GridView.

As @David suggests, maybe you're looking for [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) or [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). Both of them are technologies that could help you to fetch data dynamically.

My personal (and simple) suggestion is to implement a simple WCF service and call it when you click in the button responsible to populate the GridView for the first time. Using a polling mechanism, the WCF service should be able to fetch the data you need. Once retrieved the data, you can update the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

What about using ASP.NET AJAX?

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFromDate" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtToDate" />
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridViewSmsComplaints">
        ... Grid details ...
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="15000" ID="RefreshSmsComplaints" OnTick="RefreshSmsComplaints_Tick" />
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void RefreshSmsComplaints_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
      DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
      DataTable dt = ManageRecievedMessage.GetSmsComplaintsByDate(fromDate, toDate);
      //GridViewSmsComplaints.Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:keep-all;word-wrap:normal");

      if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
         GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
         GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;
         //gridViewComplaintsBySubject.Visible = false;
      }
      else
      {
         dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
         GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
         GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
         int totalcolums = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = totalcolums;
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data Found for this date combination";
         GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;
         //gridViewComplaintsBySubject.Visible = false;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      // Handle Exception
   }
}
```

Alternatively you can check out using SignalR as mentioned above.